# Add hyphenated form only to Hunspell personal dictionary

Tags: spell-check, hunspell

I want to add "morpho" to my personal dictionary, but only as a prefix in compound and hyphenated words. I do not want to add "morpho," since on its own it does not carry any meaning. I do not want to add specific compound/hyphenated words such as "morpho-syntax," since I'd have to do this for "morphosyntax," "morphosyntactic," etc. From the man page, it looks like I can append a slash "/" to a word to provide optional suffixes, but this means that the word itself will also count as correct. Thoughts?